# how to use service in a constructor of a class that use this service

Tags: angular, typescript

I don't succeed writing a component using Services( Injectable).
The compiler doesn't alert on the problem and it's very strange.
When I write this component (that use the service) I see nothig on the screen.

I try to write inside the ctor of the class that use the service a variable from the service type
and it cause the problem.
It seen like that:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Customer from 'src/Models/Customer';
import CustomerService from '../Services/Customer.service';
import { LogService } from '../Services/Log.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers-list',
  templateUrl: './customers-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customers-list.component.scss']
})
export class CustomersListComponent implements OnInit {
  cArr: Customer[]
  constructor(private customerSer:CustomerService,private log:LogService) {
    this.cArr = this.customerSer.arr
  }
    // public customerSer: CustomerService
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

and this is the Service class:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import Customer from "src/Models/Customer";
import { LogService } from "./Log.service";
@Injectable({providedIn:"root"})
export default class CustomerService {
    constructor(public logSer: LogService) { }
    //
    arr: Customer[] = [
        new Customer("159487", "Moshe", 6199044, "satisfied "),
        new Customer("312456", "Yosef", 5075588, "not satisfied "),
        new Customer("258741", "David", 6162696, "very satisfied "),
        new Customer("317982", "Ariel", 5704881, "satisfied "),
    ]

    updateInArr(c: Customer, status:string) {
        let index = this.arr.findIndex(item => item.id == c.id);
        this.arr[index].status=status;
        this.logSer.printUpdate(c,status)
    }

    addToArr(c:Customer){
        this.arr.push(c)
        this.logSer.printAdd(c)
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3zx8bx?file=src/app/customers-list.component.html Once I got rid of the things that were not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Angular docs](https://%20https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt4#call-it-in-ngoninit), using services in component constructor *is not the best practice* and

> Reserve the constructor for minimal initialization such as wiring constructor parameters to properties. The constructor shouldn't do anything.

Try to move getting the list from `CustomerService` to `ngOnInit()` in `CustomersListComponent` instead of its constructor:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cArr = this.customerSer.arr
}
```